# Zend Expressive API does not return contents of objects

Tags: php, json, api, mezzio

I'm creating a small API, mostly for learning purposes, but, I might implement it into a project I'm working on.  So far, I have installed the zend expressive skeleton application and set up my models and entities. I'm able to query the database and get results, but, when I return the results as a JSON Response, I can only see a list of empty arrays for each result.  I would like to be able to return the actual objects that are being returned from the database instead of converting them to arrays.

HomePageHandler.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Handler;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response\HtmlResponse;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response\JsonResponse;
use Zend\Expressive\Router;
use Zend\Expressive\Template\TemplateRendererInterface;
use App\Model\ProductModel;

class HomePageHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    /** @var string */
    private $containerName;

    /** @var Router\RouterInterface */
    private $router;

    /** @var null|TemplateRendererInterface */
    private $template;

    private $productModel;

    public function __construct(
        string $containerName,
        Router\RouterInterface $router,
        ?TemplateRendererInterface $template = null,
        ProductModel $productModel
    ) {
        $this->containerName = $containerName;
        $this->router        = $router;
        $this->template      = $template;
        $this->productModel  = $productModel;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request) : ResponseInterface
    {
        $data = $this->productModel->fetchAllProducts();

        return new JsonResponse([$data]);

        //return new HtmlResponse($this->template->render('app::home-page', $data));
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a JSON Response returned with a list of 18 "Product" entities.  My results look like.

```
[[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]]
```

Let me know if there is any other code you would like to see.
Thanks in advance!

Edited with Product.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Brock H. Caldwell
 * Date: 3/14/2019
 * Time: 4:04 PM
 */

namespace App\Entity;

class Product
{
    protected $id;
    protected $picture;
    protected $shortDescription;
    protected $longDescription;
    protected $dimensions;
    protected $price;
    protected $sold;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPicture()
    {
        return $this->picture;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $picture
     */
    public function setPicture($picture)
    {
        $this->picture = $picture;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getShortDescription()
    {
        return $this->shortDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $shortDescription
     */
    public function setShortDescription($shortDescription)
    {
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLongDescription()
    {
        return $this->longDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $longDescription
     */
    public function setLongDescription($longDescription)
    {
        $this->longDescription = $longDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDimensions()
    {
        return $this->dimensions;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $dimensions
     */
    public function setDimensions($dimensions)
    {
        $this->dimensions = $dimensions;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $price
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSold()
    {
        return $this->sold;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $sold
     */
    public function setSold($sold)
    {
        $this->sold = $sold;
    }

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->picture = (!empty($data['picture'])) ? $data['picture'] : null;
        $this->shortDescription = (!empty($data['shortDescription'])) ? $data['shortDescription'] : null;
        $this->longDescription = (!empty($data['longDescription'])) ? $data['longDescription'] : null;
        $this->dimensions = (!empty($data['dimensions'])) ? $data['dimensions'] : null;
        $this->price = (!empty($data['price'])) ? $data['price'] : null;
        $this->sold = (!empty($data['sold'])) ? $data['sold'] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the product entity class? Does it extend a class from zend?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Code has been added.  I do not extend any classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either make the properties public, or implement the `JsonSerializable` interface in your `Product` entity. All of its properties are protected, which is fine, but that means they aren't exposed when the object is JSON encoded.

Here are some brief examples:

```
class Example1 {  protected $a = 1;  }

class Example2 {  public $b = 2; }

class Example3 implements JsonSerializable {
    protected $c = 3;
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return ['c' => $this->c];
    }
}

echo json_encode([new Example1, new Example2, new Example3]);
```

The result:

```
[{},{"b":2},{"c":3}]
```

If you choose to implement `JsonSerializable`, exactly how you do it is up to you, but you just need a `jsonSerialize()` method that returns the properties you want in the JSON result in a format accessible to `json_encode` (an object with public properties or an array).

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I had a feeling that was the issue, but wasn't too sure!  I'll try this out real quick and accept the answer!

Comment: Is there anything else I have to do when I set the $data variable from the database query?

Comment: I don't think so. I beleive `$data` will just be an array of `Product` objects which will get encoded by the JsonResponse class.